# How to add new Python Modules on Mac (OSX)

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I have downloaded a module for python called *language_check*. The problem is that I do not know how to correctly install it as currently, python does not believe that the module exists. So my question is, does anyone know how I would go about installing this (or any) module on a mac? (Python version 3.5)

Comment: Are you sure you are running python 3 when you try to import? How did you install it? `pip install` or `pip3 install`?

Comment: Usually `pip`, or another Python package manager is the most convenient way to install modules.

Comment: I am running python 3. I have not heard of pip before. Any guidance on usage?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Just looked over the link I'L'I , a quick question about some stuff on there. For commands such as  pip install -U pip . Would these just be run in Terminal or in another application?